# how to obtain the second page with file_get_contents

Tags: php, web-crawler, file-get-contents

The idea is to get all the page with file_get_contents for a history record.

When I do

```
$original_file_div = file_get_contents("http://webpage.com/");
```

I have a webpage that ask for an email

If I enter to the webpage with any browser I see that page, but ... when I press refresh I have access to a new page.

I tried to do:

```
$original_file_div = file_get_contents("http://webpage.com/");
$original_file_div = file_get_contents("http://webpage.com/");
```

but still have the email page

is there any way to make refresh throw file_get_contents

I DID TRY TO POST BUT DIDN'T WORK =(

---

ADDED: The site is using Cookies

Comment: The page could be using cookies to determine whether to show the first page.

Comment: Just Check this, it's using cookies, any suggestions on how to crawl?

Comment: You can always use cURL: http://uk3.php.net/curl In fact, it's much, much better than using file_get_contents for acquiring a web page for many reasons.

Comment: thanks Rushyo ;), I don't know why somebody vote down :( the person didn't justify =(

Comment: Some people will vote down if your question is unclear or hard to understand, which yours is. What does "I DID TRY TO POST BUT DIDN'T WORK" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use curl... + accept cookies.